# RenderTransform.TranslateTransform animating in usercontrol in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

i want to create a wpf usercontrol that displays an Image and has a toolbar panel,
i want to set features listed below to the my userControl:

1. tool bar panel hidden when mouse cursor is out side of the usercontrol.
2. When mouse cursor enter the usercontrol,toolbar panel move up from the bottom of the usercontrol and locate at the bottom of the usercontrol.

i create it but ,i have a problem ,
see bellow:
[image]
when mouse cursor enter the UserControl:
[image]
and when mouse cursor leaved UserControl:
[image]
My Problem:
when panel is moving out side of the UserControl,the out side parts must be invisible,
like bellow:
[image]
my UserControl's Xaml codes:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="SB_MouseEnter">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="button_panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="SB_MouseLeave">
            <DoubleAnimation To="40" Storyboard.TargetName="button_panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SB_MouseEnter}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SB_MouseLeave}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Border CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="SeaGreen" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="Images/Koala.jpg"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="button_panel" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="40"/>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#66FFFFFF"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <Button Padding="5" Margin="5,0" Width="80" Height="30">
                    Open
                </Button>
                <Button Padding="5" Margin="5,0" Width="80" Height="30">
                    Clear
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `Clip` the `button_panel` when it leaves the `Border` with `ClipToBounds="True"` on the `Border`

something like:

```
...
<Border BorderBrush="SeaGreen"
        BorderThickness="2"
        ClipToBounds="True"
        CornerRadius="4">
...
```

Now with `ClipToBounds="True"` being set on the `Border`, any child of the `Border` which is outside the `Border` is not going to be visible.

This would thus satisfy your requirement of having the `StackPanel` invisible when the mouse is not over the image as well since `TranslateTransform` keeps it outside the `Border`. Thus you only see the `StackPanel` when mouse is over the image and the Slide in/out is only visible inside the `Border`.